# Getting an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') while using MUI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, mui-x-date-picker

I am using a MUI datepicker in the following way:

```
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker'

<DatePicker
  label="Start Date"
  name="startDate"
  inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} fullWidth variant="outlined" />
  )}
  {...register('startDate', {
    required: 'This field is required.',
  })}
/>
```

When I select date icon to choose a date and when I choose it then I am getting the following error :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at onChange (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_mui_icons-material_Add_js-node_modules_mui_icons-material_Delete_js-node-b98586.chunk.js:33269:23)
```

I am not getting why I am getting this error, as I am using in the same way as MUI has used this.

Comment: How are you even able to pass `name` as a prop to `DatePicker`? `name` isn't even available according to MUI's doc https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/

Comment: @TaiweiTuan Okay. I have removed the name prop as well. But still I am getting the same error. Can you please help here

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you're trying to use a controlled MUI component with react-hook-form

you should use `Controller` to render `DatePicker`, read more on that here [Controlled mixed with Uncontrolled Components](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#ControlledmixedwithUncontrolledComponents)

```
<Controller
  name="startDate"
  control={control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <DatePicker label="Start Date" {...field} />
  )}
/>
```

here is a codesandbox example

[image: Edit interesting-morning-5tlhmx]